# What does having a high suit temperature do?

Tags: osiris-new-dawn

By running and moving around, your suit temperature increases.  If it gets too hot (30+ °C), a warning message will appear down near the temperature gauge stating "Suit Temperature High."  Does this have any impact on your character? I haven't noticed any effects, but surely there has to be something.

What are the effects of having a high suit temperature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the game has a Wiki.  According to the [temperature page](http://osirisnewdawn.gamepedia.com/Temperature):

> Outside temperatures are primarily a threat to an astronaut's health. As long as the space suit remains sealed and intact, the temperature outside is typically just a nuisance... But if it's breached in any way, exposure is imminent and the astronaut starts freezing or starts being cooked. The ultimate difference is trivial.

The real danger of high (or very low) temperatures is if **your suit has a breach and you are exposed to lethal temperatures**.  Should you be in a very hot or cold area and your suit were to have a breach, you would begin to lose [health](http://osirisnewdawn.gamepedia.com/Health):

> Overheating or freezing due to temperature differences can lead to demise.